# Normal ordering in Sine-Gordon model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, renormalization, wick-theorem, sine-gordon

I am studying Bosonization from Giamarchi's book (Quantum Physics in 1D), in [Appendix E](https://giamarchi.unige.ch/wp-content/php_code/notes/cuso/Giamarchi/variational_BKT_quantum_physics_1d.pdf) while doing RG analysis at second order he says (Eq. E.18) that we can NOT expand cosine directly because field $\phi$ are unbounded ($<\phi^2>=\infty$) so we need to normal order cosine term, which can be done using

$$\cos(\phi)=:\cos(\phi):e^{-1/2 <\phi^2>}.$$

How does he write this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/274396/2451